# Reader-Writer and priority

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm working on a system Reader-Writer with the Java threads, and it must be prioritized : the reader has the priority over the writer.

I wrote a source-code, **which compiles and can be executed without any problem**. But I would want to be really sure it's correct.

Can you tell me if you see some errors ?

Well, first I have to explain you the aim of my little program. At regular intervals, a message is displayed to the user. The latter can modify it, and change its display delay (the "interval of time"). A message is identified by an ID.

**So if the user type : `0 \n Hello \n 2`, it means the message n°0 is now "Hello" and will be displayed every 2 seconds.**

Each message is taken care by a thread. **I have to use semaphores.**

**SOURCE-CODES.**

**The reader :**

```
public class Lecteur extends Thread {

    private Message<String> message;

    public Lecteur(Message<String> message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                System.out.println(message.getContent());
                int time = message.getRefresh_time()*1000;
                Thread.sleep(time);
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

**The writer :**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GestionnaireSaisie extends Thread {

    private HashMap<Integer, Message<String>> messages;

    public GestionnaireSaisie(HashMap<Integer, Message<String>> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    public void run() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int id;
        String content;
        int time_refresh;

        while (true) {
            id = scanner.nextInt();
            content = scanner.next();
            time_refresh = scanner.nextInt();

            Message<String> found_msg = messages.get(id);
            found_msg.setContent(content);
            found_msg.setRefreshTime(time_refresh);
        }
    }

}
```

**And the most interesting class, the shared object which contains shared data :**

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Message<T> {

    private static int maxid;
    private int id;
    private T content;
    private int refresh_time;

    public Semaphore mutex_content, mutex_refresh_time, semNbl;
    public static int nbL = 0;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Message(T content, int refresh_time, Semaphore mutex_content, Semaphore mutex_refresh_time, Semaphore semNbl) {
        id = maxid;
        Message.maxid++;
        this.content = content;
        this.refresh_time = refresh_time;

        this.mutex_content = mutex_content;
        this.mutex_refresh_time = mutex_refresh_time;
        this.semNbl = semNbl;
    }

    // <!-- CONTENT
    public void setContent(T content) {
        try {
            mutex_content.acquire();
            this.content = content;
            mutex_content.release();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public T getContent() {
        T ret = null;
        try {
            semNbl.acquire();
            Message.nbL++;
            if(Message.nbL == 1) {
                mutex_content.acquire();
            }
            semNbl.release();

            ret = content;

            semNbl.acquire();
            Message.nbL--;
            if(Message.nbL == 0) {
                mutex_content.release();
            }
            semNbl.release();

        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return ret;
    }
    // CONTENT -->

    // <!-- REFRESH TIME
    public void setRefreshTime(int refresh_time) {
        try {
            mutex_refresh_time.acquire();
            this.refresh_time = refresh_time;
            mutex_refresh_time.release();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public int getRefresh_time() {
        int ret = 0;

        try {
            semNbl.acquire();
            Message.nbL++;
            if(Message.nbL == 1) {
                mutex_refresh_time.acquire();
            }
            semNbl.release();

            ret = refresh_time;

            semNbl.acquire();
            Message.nbL--;
            if(Message.nbL == 0) {
                mutex_refresh_time.release();
            }
            semNbl.release();

        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return ret;
    }
    // REFRESH TIME -->
}
```

**Here some code to test it :**

```
Semaphore mutex_content = new Semaphore(1);
Semaphore mutex_refresh_time = new Semaphore(1);
Semaphore semNbl = new Semaphore(1);

Message<String> message1 = new Message<String>("Bonjour le monde !", 5, mutex_content, mutex_refresh_time, semNbl);
new Lecteur(message1).start();

HashMap<Integer, Message<String>> messages = new HashMap<Integer, Message<String>>();
messages.put(message1.getId(), message1);
GestionnaireSaisie gs = new GestionnaireSaisie(messages);
gs.start();
```

Comment: Why nbL is static?

Comment: To be shared to all the objects. nbL is the number of readers.

Comment: Heem someone could help me please ?

Comment: same question"Why nbL is static? ". Either I don't understand the code or the code is messy.

Comment: Well nbL is shared between all the :Message objects.